# Destiny weapon and armor statistics

Tags: destiny

I recently noticed that next to some of the weapons' attack power statistic, there is a slash and then another number. This is also true for armor. I would assume that it means that is the amount of damage/protection once fully upgraded. Also, next to some of the armor that has strength/discipline/intellect/light bonuses, there is also a slash and then another number. However, this number is usually only one or two higher than the original number. I am a level 20 Titan. Can anyone tell me what these mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first number is the current value of the armor or damage the weapon does. The second number, as you say, is the value it´ll have once fully upgraded.

Comment: You might want to amplify that when fully upgraded, the two numbers will be the same, which may be why OP is seeing values separated by not very much.